# Netbeans keyboard shortcut for navigating to next error marker in editor

Tags: netbeans

Is there any keyboard shortcut key for navigating to the next error (red markers created in error stripe) in Netbeans editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Period</kbd> ::: (<kbd>Period</kbd> means <kbd>.</kbd>)

Links to many shortcuts:

- [Highlights of NetBeans IDE 8.0 Keyboard Shortcuts & Code
  Templates](https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/usersguide/shortcuts-80.pdf)
- [134 Shortcuts for NetBeans 8 (Windows)](https://shortcutworld.com/NetBeans/win/NetBeans_8_Shortcuts)

***EDITED--URLs NOW VALID*** thru ver. 8

Comment: By clicking on the error you'd find the error location. As far as I know it is the way.

Comment: The link to the shortcuts is no longer valid and this shortcut didn't work for me (although, I'm using JVI in Netbeans so that may interfere)

Comment: Here's a link to the shortcuts: https://usersguide.netbeans.org/shortcuts.pdf - they don't all work on my Mac, but again, that maybe JVI.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, the question is about moving the cursor within the editor window to the next red wavy underline error marker, which would be very handy, but the provided shortcut doesn't work (NB8 on Linux). Anyone cares to provide a correct answer?

Comment: As of Netbeans 8 this shortcut only jumps to the next occurrence of a search result set.

Answer (score 11):

As of `NetBeans 8` there doesn't appear to be a way to navigate through errors exclusively in the editor.  If you look at **tools**->**options**->**keymap** an action does exist for this (next error in editor), but the shortcut is blank.  I set it to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> on my IDE, this will navigate through all annotations - not just errors.  So if you don't mind cycling through all hints, warnings errors, etc, this will work.

The closest I've been able to get for navigating specifically through errors is using the action items window.  Add a filter for `errors`, then you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to navigate through the list (see [How to display all compile errors in Netbeans as a task list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143726/how-to-display-all-compile-errors-in-netbeans-as-a-task-list)).

Comment: I removed system 'next error' and 'previous error' shortcuts (which was Ctr+. and Ctrl+, respectively) and remapped Ctrl+. to 'next error in editor'. But it just does not work, nothing happens when I press Ctrl+. being in the editor window :( I am on Linux. Edit: Now I found out why it does not work. There is a NullPointerException happening for some reason.

Comment: NullPointerException still occurs in Netbeans 8.2 on Windows. Have reported, but still no fix.

Answer (score 2):

Add the Action Items window to your IDE. This lists all of your errors and is dynamic, so will be updated when you save.
From the menu bar: Window->Action Items.
(Took me forever to understand why when I would save, I wouldn't see any compile errors, but then it wouldn't run.)

Answer (score 2):

Actually question is about "next error **in editor**". At least in my configuration (NetBeans profile) this function doesn't have any shortcut by default so if you go to Tools->Options->Keymap and in search field you write "Next Error in Editor" you can add any shortcut that fits the best to you

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac things are different and there is *no* keyboard shortcut for navigating to a usage/compile error as far as I can tell.

You can go to Help -> Keyboard Shortcuts Card to see the full list of short cuts for your platform.

See https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/mac.html for info for macs and https://usersguide.netbeans.org/shortcuts.pdf for the default shortcuts for PCs.

Answer (score 0):

No. there is no good and easy way on keyboard.
just clicking on those red marks (by mouse) is the fastest way. (it's not an easy/good way. but the best possible.)