# How to display all compile errors in Netbeans as a task list?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7.2

Is there a way in Netbeans 7.2 to have all compile errors of all open projects display in some task list, just like the "Action Items" do? I just can't find any.

The reason behind this is that I make some method signature change that for example affects 20 different callers which I'd like to change successively without having to work through the project tree.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

1. You can create a filter for this in the *Action Items* Window: **Action
   Items Filter -> New** (check *compile errors*)
2. Set **scope** of *Action Items* to "*all opened projects*"