# Netbeans didn't catch error for function that should have return something, not having a return statment

Tags: netbeans, c++

I was surprised to find the compiler gave no warnings or errors when compiling source code containing a function that specified a return value in its signature but didn't actually return anything

e.g.

```
int foo()
{

}
```

How can Netbeans be beefed up so it caches these things?

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614282/why-does-this-c-snippet-compile-non-void-function-does-not-return-a-value) this is undefined behaviour but I would've thought this is something easy for an IDE to check for.

Also, is there a way to have it displays number of warnings at the bottom of the output window after compiling? For example the way it is by default, a warning could be buried in the amount of irrelevant information and easily missed.

Comment: properly configured your compiler should check this and issue a proper warning. (something to the effect of "non-void function should return a value"). Also, an equally UB-scenario involves a valueless return statement in a similar function (e.g.: `return;`). Netbeans uses an external compiler (often gcc or clang) so make sure your warning levels for your toolset are cranked up. Examples: warnings-as-errors (-Werror), all common warnings (-Wall) and extra less common warnings (-Wextra), for example. -Wreturn-type is the specific one I think you seek.

Answer (score 0):

> How can Netbeans be beefed up so it caches these things?

**`Right click to project -> C++ Compiler`** set **`Warning Level`** to **`More Warnings`** (below *Basic Options*).

(Same applies to *C Compiler settings*)

**Or:**

Add `-Wall` to compiler flags.

For a maximum of warnings you can add these: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

> Also, is there a way to have it displays number of warnings at the bottom of the output window after compiling?

I guess there's no number yet, but possible this can help you: [How to display all compile errors in Netbeans as a task list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143726/how-to-display-all-compile-errors-in-netbeans-as-a-task-list/12144068#12144068)